# slim_tag: Is there something like haml_tag in slim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

In HAML, we have the [haml_tag helper](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_tag-instance_method). Is there a slim_tag helper in slim? Has anyone implemented it yet?

Comment: I'm just curious, what would the use-case be for this? It seems to me like it would be somewhat useless, as you could simply do `.table` as opposed to doing something like `slim_tag :table`, as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Slim splat attributes for that using *. See the README.